# Missing something when adding AD users with powershell

Tags: active-directory, powershell, csv

I'm going round in circles and hoping someone can point me in the right direction...

I have created a .csv file as follows

```
SamAccountName,Name,GivenName,Surname,DisplayName,Type,Path,Logon Name,UserPrincipleName,ScriptPath,Password
fredflinstone,Fred Flinstone,Fred,Flinstone,Fred Flinstone,User,"CN=users,DC=Test,DC=local",fredf@test.local,fredf@test.local,login.bat,Yabba
```

I go to powershell, run

```
import-module activedirectory
Import-CSV C:\Users1.csv | New-ADUser
```

It successfully adds the users but the issues I have are

1. it doesn't actually put in the `Account User login name` but does put in the pre 2000 name.
2. it doesn't put in the password
3. Even if I put in the Enabled field with the value $true they are still disabled

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 7):

1. Logon Name is not one of the parameters that New-ADUser takes. See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617253.aspx for a list of what you can use.
2. Password won't work this way, as it has to be a SecureString for security reasons. If you want to load the password from the cSV you'll have to turn this into a fuller script that can convery the value form the CSV into a secureString.
3. I wonder if enabled is being set with the string "$true" instead of the boolean value,a s a result of coming thru a CSV file?

Comment: Also, it's UserPrincipalName, not UserPrincipleName.

Answer (score 2):

The Above are correct, you need to have `UserPrincipalName` something like this if gabbing information from an CSV:

```
-UserPrincipalName ($_.SamAccountName + '@' + $_.DomainName)
```

`SamAccountName` and `DomainName` are both Columns in my CSV spreadsheet.

Comment: This works nicely, but isn't required--you can still manually specify the UPN if you want to.

Comment: Yes, of course just like everything to be automatic :) thanks for the comments guys, just getting started here!

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to populate "userPrincipalName" for the "User Login Name".
2. Get-Help Set-ADAccountPassword -examples : the first one shows you how to set an AD password.
3. As you haven't set a password, you can't enable the account regardless.

So your script will have three calls:

```
Create the user (New-ADUser)
Set the password (Set-ADAccountPassword)
Enable the user (Set-ADUser)
```

Comment: Thanks guys.  I did have the spelling for Principal incorrect in the CSV file...that was my first issue.   Since then we have completed this particular job.  I just did a generic password manually and let them all set them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a variable option:

```
$a = Get-Date
$Man = $a.Month
$ti = $a.Hour
$min =$a.Minute
-AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "Password$Man$ti$min" -Force)
```

Comment: what is adding random numbers to the password supposed to accomplish?

Answer (score -1):

The password part can be solved by this

```
-AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "12345678" -Force)
```

where you can swap `12345678` with a variable.